# Can only grab last values from array - PHP

Tags: php, file-io

Why does this only show the last username and password? Before people start complaining about storing passwords in a text file etc. I'm only doing this for testing purposes. Not going to actually be storing these passwords in a **text file.**

```
$lines = file('users.txt');
$userlist = array();

foreach($lines as $line) {
if(empty($line)) continue;

// whole line
$line = trim(str_replace(": ", ':', $line));
$lineArr = explode(' ', $line);

// username only
$username = explode(':', $lineArr[0]);
$username = array_pop($username);

// password
$password = explode(':', $lineArr[1]);
$password = array_pop($password);

// putting them together
$userlist[$username] = $password;   

}

$user = $username;
$pass = $password;

echo "$user";
echo " $pass";
```

Comment: Because your echo isn't within the foreach loop

Comment: hahaha wow. What a rookie error. Thank you very much.